# Did Aurangzeb issue a farman promising 4 Rs for all males that convert and 2 Rs for females?

Tags: middle-ages, india, islam, mughals, south-asia

I found a reference to this *[farman](https://www.iranicaonline.org/articles/farman)* at [IranicaOnline](https://www.google.co.in/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=asad%20khan%20rupees%20two%20rupees%20four%20aurangzeb) (first link)
[image: picture of a book citation.]

But I can't find the source of the author (or if its authentic). Is it from an *akhbar* or from a biography of Aurangzeb? Its mentioned as a *farman* [here](https://t.co/R7uQP1bT5Q), but I'm told that the site is not very trustworthy.

[Jadunath Sarkar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jadunath_Sarkar) mentions some [akhbar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akhbar) related to inducements for conversion, but I can't verify whether this *farman* is among those *[akhbarat](https://itihas-dictionary.blogspot.com/2010/05/akhbarat.html)* ([text version](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.537060/2015.537060.History-_djvu.txt)) [image]

Comment: The mention of Elliot is almost certainly a reference to [The History of India, as Told by Its Own Historians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_History_of_India,_as_Told_by_Its_Own_Historians) which may be one of the sources...

Comment: Yes, but the reference is correct, but its for a pre-Mughal dynasty. Can't find his M.A. (Mirat-e-alam) Page 508 reference though..

Comment: Then you may want an accessible version of [Mirat al alam : History of Awrangzeb, 1658-1668](https://books.google.com/books/about/Mirat_al_alam_History_of_Awrangzeb_1658.html?id=p0ktAQAAIAAJ).

Comment: A page [here](https://factmuseum.com/aurangzeb-as-he-was-according-to-mughal-records/) discusses this, and shows some images of text possibly related to this passage, under entry 43:'Siyah Akhbarat-i-Darbar-i- Mu‘alla Julus (R.Yr.) 28 Jamadi I, 12 / 7th April 1685'.

Comment: The text in the image is not eligible and there is no way to cross-check the reference mentioned in it. Plus, the tone of that site is polemical rather than scholarly.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. He did donate money to convert people to Islam.

[image: Exhibit No. 43]

> "(The Emperor) ordered Jumadat-ul-Mulk to write to all the Faudjars
>   and Diwans of the kingdom that each Hindu male who becomes a Musalman,
>   is to be given Rupees four and each Hindu woman Rupees two, as fixed
>   by us, from the treasury of the place, by way of inam.
>
> Those who become Musalman out of devotion for Din (Islam), in their
>   case, the award of money in future be stopped."

Note:

The amount offered as an inducement for conversion was substantial and amounted to almost one month's wages of a worker in case of a Hindu male.

The document forms one of the most unabashed statement and the severest indictment on the methods adopted in spreading Islam in India, and this was being done even more than four hundred after the establishment of Muslim rule in India (c. 1200 A.D.)!

Source:

[Aurangzeb, as he was according to Mughal Records](http://www.aurangzeb.info/)

Comment: Can you give me a source for this **farman** in any scholarly book? This image has been circulating for a while, and its difficult to verify its authenticity

Answer (score 3):

[image: This is original document placed in state museum bikaner rajasthan][image]
This is original pic of document placed at state museum bikaner rajasthan

Comment: @sempaiscuba and Amit: Should this be worked into the longer answer above?

Answer (score -1):

It's practically impossible here's why:
Any Hindu can come and say yes I have converted to Islam, take so called 4 Rupa and go away. How will Aurangzeb verify if that Hindu is really practicing Islam or not? I don't think Aurangzeb was that stupid.

Comment: The fact that it could be subverted doesn't mean that it wasn't attempted.